# Absolute stability theoretical and empirical comparison

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Regard the diff equation:

$m \phi'' +a\phi'+(mg/L)\phi=0$

$\phi(0)=0.1$

$\phi'(0)=0$

where $m=0.1,  L=1, a=2,$

1) Rewrite the second order diff equation as a system of first order linear equations

2) Test to find a step where the solution is not stable (with matlab)

3) Test to see if the theory for absolute stability agrees with the empirical tests for which the step length makes the system stable

Solution:

1) I found the system of equations to be:

$y_1'=y_2$

$y_2'=-(a/m)y_2-(g/L)y_1$

$y_1(0)=0.1$

$y_2(0)=0$

2) $h<0.1$ for the system to be stable

3) How do I test if the theory agrees?

I have came up with this vector equation:

$$y'=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        -a/m & -g/L  \\
        \end{pmatrix}y$$

This matrix we can write as a diagonal matrix and use the eigenvalues to determine absolute stability:

$$D =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & -9.81  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

The matrix diagonal entries represent the eigenvalues of the matrix

So if $(1+h\lambda_j)<1$ then if we solve for $h$ we can find the required step for absolute stability.

I don't know really how to proceed since the first eigenvalue is positive.

Any help is appreciated. I guess I have done something wrong previously to come to this matrix

Comment: This is not the correct matrix.

Comment: Could you show me what the correct one is? And explain if possible the idea behind it. Thanks :)

Comment: Wait, you cannot transform $y_1'=y_2$, $y_2'=-(a/m)y_2-(g/L)y_1$, into a first order two-dimensional differential system? Then **this** should be your question.

Comment: Yes, should I ask it on a new post-question? I thought I had done it right

Comment: Isn't $y′_1=y_2, y′_2=−(a/m)y_2−(g/L)y_1$ a two dimensional first order diff system?

Comment: Yes, but your matrix is wrong. The first equation there reads as $y_1'=y_1$.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of this linear ODE is 
$$
0=mλ^2+aλ+(mg/L)
$$
with solutions
$$
λ_{1/2}=-\frac{a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4m^2g/L}}{2m}=-\frac{2mg/L}{a\mp\sqrt{a^2-4m^2g/L}}
$$
Both forms tell us that for $a>0$ the roots are negative or have negative real part.

With $m=0.1$, $L=1$, $a=2$, $g=9.81$ this gives
$$
λ_1=-10·(1+\sqrt{1-0.0981}),\quad λ_2=-\frac{0.981}{1+\sqrt{1-0.0981}}
$$