# Find the first order system of linear equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Regard the diff equation:

$mϕ′′+aϕ′+(mg/L)ϕ=0$

$ϕ(0)=0.1$

$ϕ′(0)=0$

where $m=0.1,L=1,a=2,$

1) Rewrite the second order diff equation as a system of first order linear equations.

2) What is the matrix that comes from the rewritten equations?

Comment: can you write $x'' + x' + x = 0$ as a system of first order equations?

Comment: Set $x_1=x$ and $x_2=x'$. Calculate $x_1'$ and $x_2'$

Comment: in this problem, set $x_1 = \phi, x_2 = \phi'$

Comment: Asked again at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225244/18398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if we set $$x_1 = \phi, x_2 = \phi' $$ we have 
$$\begin{align}x_1' &=  0x_1 + x_2\\ x_2'&= -\frac gL x_1-\frac am x_2\end{align} $$  in matrix notation, we have $$(x_1, x_2)^T = x' = \pmatrix{0&1\\-\frac gL &-\frac am }x $$

Answer (score 1):

For (1), start by letting $\phi_1 = \phi$, and $\phi_2 = \phi'$. Now, write $\phi_1'$ and $\phi_2'$.

This should lead immediately to (2).

Comment: That is what I did but when I get the matrix to find the step for absolute stability I get the wrong matrix. Can you please check this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222401/absolute-stability-theoretical-and-empirical-comparison?noredirect=1#comment2487003_1222401

Comment: @Nash You did not set up the matrix properly there. There is a subtle mistake. Note that since $\phi_1 = \phi$, then $\phi_1' = \phi'.$ But, $\phi'$ is defined as $\phi_2$. Therefore, we can write $\phi_1' = 0\cdot \phi_1 + 1\cdot \phi_2$. This should give you your top row.

Comment: I think that is what I have done. If you check the second row the first component of the matrix is with regard to $\phi_2$ Have I got it mixed up? How is the matrix supposed to look?

Comment: @Nash It is not what you have done because your top row in the matrix is not correct. Perhaps re-trace my steps and think on it a little bit.

Comment: I will do that! Thanks :)