# System of first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Regard the diff equation that includes $sin(\phi)$:

$mϕ′′+aϕ′+(mg/L)sin(ϕ)=0$

$ϕ(0)=0.1$

$ϕ′(0)=0$

where $m=0.1,L=1,a=2,$

How can i rewrite the second order diff equation as a system of first order linear equations?

Comment: You asked this exact same question yesterday [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222542/find-the-first-order-system-of-linear-equations). Voting to close.

Comment: You even accepted the answer in your other question, and then you asked it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any way to get rid of the sine to make it linear, but we can use the standard trick to rewrite it as a first order equation: Let $\psi = \binom\phi{\phi'}$, then
\begin{align*}
  \psi' &= \binom{\phi'}{\phi''}\\
        &= \binom{\phi'}{\frac am\phi' + \frac gL\sin\phi}\\
        &= \binom{\psi_2}{\frac am \psi_2 + \frac gL \sin\psi_1}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question: Why can't we set $y = < sin(\phi), \phi'> $?

Comment: We can. But it does not really help, we have then $y' = \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<\cos\phi \phi', \phi''> = \<\sqrt{1 - y_1^2}y_2, \frac am y_2 + \frac gL y_1>$, which is also nonlinear.